# Let $f:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be $C^2$ and $f(tx)=t^2f(x)$, then exisis $B:\mathbb{R}^m\times\mathbb{R}^m$ bilinear s.t. $f(x)=B(x,x)$

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

### Let $f:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be $C^2$ and $f(tx)=t^2f(x)$, for all $r\in\mathbb{R}$ and all $x\in\mathbb{R}^m$, then exisis $B:\mathbb{R}^m\times\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ bilinear s.t. $f(x)=B(x,x)$

I think what i thought doesn't help at all, but here it is:
I was trying to look at the fact that, as $f$ is differentiable, then
$$f(x)=f(0)-f'(0)(x)+r(x)$$
But $f(0)=0^2f(x)=0$, then
$$f(x)=-f'(0)x+r(x)$$
And,
$$f(tx)=-tf'(0)x+r(tx)$$
But, $f(tx)=t^2f(x)$, then
$$-tf'(0)x+r(tx)=-t^2f'(0)x+t^2r(x)$$
then
$$t^2(f'(0)x-r(x))-tf'(0)x+r(tx)=0$$
And I'm stuck here.

Comment: @TsemoAristide what do you mean by "How can you write"?

Comment: But $B:\mathbb{R}^m\times\mathbb{R}^m$

Comment: You write that $f'(0) = 0^2f(x) = 0$; I believe you mean that $f(0) = 0^2f(x) = 0$.

Comment: The following suggestion is related to a correspondence between quadratic forms and bilinear forms; try $B(x,y) = \frac{1}{2}(f(x+y) - f(x) - f(y))$. It is not clear to me however that $B$ is bilinear in this case, but it does give $f(x) = B(x,x)$.

Comment: Note that $C^2$ is indeed needed. With $C^1$ only one can easily come up with counterexamples even for $m=2$, $n=1$.

Answer (score 2):

We may assume $n=1$. According to Taylor's theorem for $C^2$-functions of $m$ variables one has
$$f(x)=f(0)+df(0).x+{1\over2}d^2f(0).(x,x)+o\bigl(|x|^2\bigr)\qquad(x\to0)\ .\tag{1}$$
Here $d^2f(0)=:2B$ is the Hessian of $f$ at $0$. Now fix a $y\in{\mathbb R}^m$, and put $x:=t y$ in $(1)$, $t\in{\mathbb R}$. Then
$$t^2 f(y)=f(0)+t df(0).y+t^2\>B(y,y)+o(t^2)\quad(t\to0)\ .$$
This can hold only if $f(0)=0$, $df(0).y=0$, and $f(y)=B(y,y)$. As $y$ was arbitrary this implies $df(0)=0$ and $f(y)=B(y,y)$.

Answer (score 1):

You can continue as follows:

$t^2(f'(0)x-r(x)) -tf'(0)x+r(tx)=0$ implies that $f'(0)(x)= -t(f'(0)x-r(x)) -{{r(tx)}\over{t\|x\|}}\|x\|$ but you have $lim_{t\rightarrow 0}{{r(tx)}\over{t\|x\|}}=0$ since $f$ is differentiable. You deduce that $f'(0)=0$.

Now write the second limit development around $0$ $f(x) =d^2f(0)(x,x)+\|x\|^2e(x)$ where $lim_{t\rightarrow 0}e(x)=0$, $f(tx)=t^2d^2f(x,x)+t^2\|x\|e(tx)=t^2d^2f(0)(x,x)+t^2\|x\|^2e(x)$. This implies that $e(tx)=e(x)$ for every $t$ this implies that $e(x)=lim_{t\rightarrow 0}e(tx)=0$.

The bilinear map $B=df^2(0)$.